# Render Result vs Viewer Node

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am pretty new to blender and I am sure someone has asked this question before.. but basically I am following along with this tutorial and I added all these nodes in the compositing view.. Basically whenever I render my image or animation it doesn't have any of the nodes I added... like color or a little bit of blur etc... Here is an image of what I want it to look like vs how it is rendering... [image]

I want my final animation to look like the centered image.. but whenever I render it looks like the bottom left image.. I am sure there is some small detail I am missing or something... Please help me!!!!

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of your compositor node setup, or better yet, share the .blend file. The latter can be uploaded to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Don't forget to edit the question to include the link to the file.

Comment: If you want to save the viewer output from the image editor, you can also press the F3 key to save it.

Answer (score 1):

The *Composite Node*(or the *Render Result*) outputs to the image editor and is your final render and is where you save from. The viewer node is used as a backdrop for the compositor. It's not intended for a final render but rather to preview the render result allowing you to more easily adjust compositor settings.

Also in the compositor make sure you check *Use Nodes* and *Backdrop*. The backdrop is used to see what is inputted into the *Viewer* node.

Viewer Node: https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/compositing/types/output/viewer.html

Composite Node:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/compositing/types/output/composite.html